# How to Import AAR file in the flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, dart

How to import .aar file to a Flutter project, and use it?
I am using Flutter 3.13.8  Dart 3.1.4 , Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73724659/how-to-import-aar-file-in-the-flutter-plugin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669038/how-to-build-flutter-project-with-android-aar-file

Answer (score 0):

Create a dir called libs at android/app/src/main and put your .aar files into the libs folder.

Then in app build.grade put the following line for each library in the dependencies block:

```
implementation files("D:\\yourflutterproject\\android\\app\\src\\main\\libs\\lib.aar")
```